# mysql grant remote permissions via non-root user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, permissions

I have two remote ubuntu servers. I want to allow mysql access from one to the other. I don't have the root password to the remote machine that will be running the database queries.

Is it possible to grant access to a remote connection without being logged into mysql as root? I can log in as another mysql user and I also have root SSH access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with root SSH access you can restart MySQL and tell it not to check for the root password by running (once MySQL has been stopped) 'sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &' then you could create a user and grant that user the grant_option.